# Should i DeepCopy the List<T> rather than creating isntances from it from JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, clone, deep-copy

I have a List of objects for example `List<Employee>`, Every employee in the list will load from .JSON file. i also need to create new instances from `List<Employee>` and just change properties of new instance for the new employee i need to create because JSON file have an architecture or workflow base for every employee that i don't need to creating from scratch every time i need instance of `List<Employee>`

**Briefly,**
When i need a new instance ? should i create `List<Employee>` and read JSON file again .
Or should i use `DeepCloner` extension as example ? for cloning the base `List<Employee>` and start new instance of List ?

Also the json file maybe changed later. so the Cloner will just use old List of employee !

i find performance awesome when using DeepCloner extension for creating more than 10 instances from the main `List<Employee>`. but creating a `List<Employee>` from reading same JSON file again take more time.

What is good scenario for this, first instance must load from json, but what about second and third instances? should it reading json also ? json maybe changed later? or just do DeepCloner ? or how to achieve it well.

**Keywords:**
Main `List<Employee>` : this main a first instance that must reading from JSON.

**Mihir Dave** answer it good for me.

Comment: You're deserializing a list from JSON, but after that it's a little bit hard to follow what's happening, like why the objects change, and what the connection is to the original JSON files if they change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to implement this i would do something like below.

let's assume DeepCloneris kind of caching mechanism. and when using cache you should think about cache busting also.

so how we'll implement that?

Create a method that returns List along with two static variables

```
private static List<Employee> globalEmployees = null;
private static DateTime globalFileModifiedTime;

public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{}
```

Now, this method should know when to read from the file and when to use DeepCloner.

**When not to use DeepCloner?**

- When `globalEmployees` is null
- When Global Employee File modified time is newer than what we have stored in `globalFileModifiedTime`

Note: Every time you read from a file, update `globalEmployees` and `globalFileModifiedTime` so you can use DeepCloner for next Requests

For any other use cases, you can use DeepCloner.

Comment: But, did you suggest a good thing than DeepCloner ? or let it just work normally and always Read from JSON ?

Comment: DeepCloner can be used in a wide range of use cases. this solution that I mentioned is better than using just DeepCloner alone for just this use case. And YES you should use this approach instead of always reading JSON from file.

Comment: Man, please i have another question the List of employee cannot be static because its declared in a class that can holds also a List of customers !   so please how to make this global list of employee non static ! that also make a class can has a list of customer if its initialized with contrusctor that say its a customer class that holds list of customers not employee. as example.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't have a static list in a normal class. anyway if you are facing difficulties you can move your list and time variable in another static class and access it from there.

Comment: because a static class not for employee. it maybe for customer instance